# Make elpy-shell-send more intelligent

Tags: python, elpy

How can I modify (or replace) `elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer` (bound to `C-c C-c`) to behave like `ess-eval-region-or-function-or-paragraph-and-step`, i.e.

1. if region is active, evaluate it (this currently works), goto 4.
2. if inside a function, evaluate it, goto 4.
3. evaluate current paragraph
4. Jump to the beginning of next paragraph

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this thoroughly, but should work:
1. if region is active, evaluate it (this currently works), goto 3.
2. if region not active, evaluate current statement, goto 3.
3. Jump to the beginning of next paragraph

```
(defun python-shell-send-region-or-line nil
  "Sends from python-mode buffer to a python shell, intelligently."
  (interactive)
  (cond ((region-active-p)
     (setq deactivate-mark t)
     (python-shell-send-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
     (python-nav-forward-statement)
 ) (t (elpy-shell-send-current-statement))))
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35934972/emacs-elisp-send-line-if-no-region-active-python-mode/40152990#40152990).

Answer (score 1):

`elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer` is meant only to send entire buffer or a region.

If you want to step through code, you should use `elpy-shell-send-current-statement`, which is bound to `C-ENTER`. This function sends current statement to Python shell and advances to next.

If you want to send entire function, you have to use `python-shell-send-defun` which is bound to `C-M-x`.